# I have unmounted a partition, yet mkfs.ext4 says it won't run on a partition in use, why is that?

Tags: mount, opensuse, mkfs

`/dev/sda11` is a partition that I'd like install NixOS 18.03 on following [this guide](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Installing_from_Linux). The problem is that `/dev/sda11` is unmounted, yet `mkfs.ext4` is acting like it is still is mounted. I had it mounted in `/fedora-28` (I originally intended to use it for Fedora 28 beta), with `/dev`, `/sys` and `/proc` mounted up (for chrooting purposes), yet for some reason even though I unmounted it with:

```
sudo umount /fedora-28 -l
```

running:

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 -L 'NixOS 18.03' /dev/sda11
```

returns the error:

```
/dev/sda11 is apparently in use by the system; will not make a filesystem here!
```

Here's the kicker, just to prove I hadn't unknowingly mounted it somewhere else I ran:

```
sudo umount /dev/sda11
```

and it too confirmed the fact that it was unmounted, with the output:

```
umount: /dev/sda11: not mounted.
```

So does anyone know what I should do? Besides the obvious, that is, rebooting? If relevant I am using openSUSE Tumbleweed, although I have had this problem on other distributions.

Comment: Try the `lsof` and/or `fuser` commands on `/dev/sda11` to find if something is still accessing it.

Comment: @JdeBP This problem has obviously a different reason so why should the question be a duplicate?